# Number guessing game in C, After winning and guessed after n attempts of guesses how to ask to Play again?

Tags: c

**Here is my code for a number guessing game?** I want to add a Play again option by asking yes or no if yes the game start again if no game terminates. How to do that? with in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int number, guess, nguesses=1;
    char answer='y';

    srand(time(0));
    number = rand()%100+1;
    
    do{
        printf("Guess the number between 1 to 100\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        if(guess>100){
        printf("Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 200.\n");
        printf("Try again.\n ");
        }
        else if(guess>number){
        printf("Lower Number Please!\n");
        }
        else if(guess<number){
        printf("Higher number please!\n");
        }
        else{
        printf("You guessed it in %d attempts\n", nguesses);
        }
        nguesses++;
    
    }while(guess!=number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the guess code into a function. Then have a loop in main that calls the function, then asks user whether to continue and either continues at the top of the loop or exits the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ask the player if he wants to play again. If you ask for a character you will have to take care of the `\n` left in the buffer after reading the last number, so I've asked the user to input number 1 if he wants to play again and a different value to exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    int number, guess, nguesses;
    int replay = 1;

    while(replay == 1)
    {
       nguesses = 1; // important to initialize for each game
       srand(time(0));
       number = rand()%100+1;
    
       do{
          printf("Guess the number between 1 to 100\n");
          scanf("%d", &guess);

           if(guess>100){
               printf("Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 100.\n");
               printf("Try again.\n ");
           }
           else if(guess>number){
               printf("Lower Number Please!\n");
           }
           else if(guess<number){
              printf("Higher number please!\n");
           }
            else{
               printf("You guessed it in %d attempts\n", nguesses);
           }
           nguesses++;
       }while(guess!=number);
       printf("Press 1 if you want to play again. Press other value to exit. Your choice: ");
       scanf("%d", &replay);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your error message has a little mistake, you are using `200`, not `100`:

```
if(guess>100){
    printf("Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 200.\n");
```

You also need to move your `nguesses = 1;` to be inside your repetition, otherwise the number of guesses from previous games will accumulate.

Comment: you should move your `srand(time(0));` out of `while`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this . A loop to ask after every iteration he want to play again or not.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int number, guess, nguesses=1;
    char answer='y';
    srand(time(0));
    while (true) {
        
        number = rand() % 100 + 1;

        do {
            printf("Guess the number between 1 to 100\n");
            scanf("%d", &guess);

            if (guess > 100) {
                printf("Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 200.\n");
                printf("Try again.\n ");
            } else if (guess > number) {
                printf("Lower Number Please!\n");
            } else if (guess < number) {
                printf("Higher number please!\n");
            } else {
                printf("You guessed it in %d attempts\n", nguesses);
            }
            nguesses++;

        } while (guess != number);
        printf("Want to play again\n", answer);
        scanf("%c", &answer);
        if (answer != 'Y')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't work. There is a `\n'` left in the buffer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach. You can make a function that asks the user if he/ she wants to play again and then return a value accordingly. If the user wants to exit, the program will break. If the user chooses to play again, the program will reinitialize the nuguesses and the pseudo random number and then continue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int playAgain();

int main()
{
    int number, guess, nguesses=1, again;
    char answer='y';

    srand(time(0));
    number = rand()%100+1;
    
    do{
        printf("Guess the number between 1 to 100\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        if(guess>100){
        printf("Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 200.\n");
        printf("Try again.\n ");
        }
        else if(guess>number){
        printf("Lower Number Please!\n");
        }
        else if(guess<number){
        printf("Higher number please!\n");
        }
        else{
        printf("You guessed it in %d attempts\n", nguesses);
        // asking the user if he wants to play again after guessing correctly
        again = playAgain();
        if(!again)
            break;
        else
        { 
          // reinitialize and continue
          nguesses = 1;
          srand(time(0));
          number = rand()%100+1;
          continue;
        }
        }
        nguesses++;
    
    }while(guess!=number);

    return 0;
}

int playAgain()
{
    char choice;
    printf("Do you want to play again?");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    if(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```